# Problems in binary tree traversal

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to implement a binary search tree with In order traversal. I am trying to print a series of numbers after each other to test it. It seems that it is sorting well, however it is printing dublicate numbers sometimes. Look at relevant pieces of my code:

Tree class and Methods:

```
 public class Tree {
Node root;

public Tree(){
root = null;
}


public Node add(Node n, int value){
if(n== null){
    n= new Node(value);
}else if(value < n.getValue()){
    n.addLeftNode(add(n.getLeft(),value));
}else if(value > n.getValue()){
    n.addRightNode(add(n.getRight(),value));
}

return n;
}

public static Node traverse(Node n){

Node result = new Node();

if(n != null){


    if(n.getLeft() != null){

        result = traverse(n.getLeft()); 
        System.out.println(result.getValue());                
    }

        result = n;
        System.out.println(result.getValue());      


    if(n.getRight() != null){     

        result = traverse(n.getRight());
        System.out.println(result.getValue());

    }

}
return result;
}
}
```

This is what it's printing out:

---

0
0
1
1
3
4
4
5
6
7
7
8
10
11
12
12
12
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
16
18
18
20
21
22
22
22
22
23
27
28
28
28
29
34
35
43
43
43
43
43
43
43
44
45
45
55
56
59
66
75
75
75
75
75
75
76
76
76
78
88
89
89
90
90
90
98
98

Any clues? I'm guessing it's something with the traversal. Tried debugging it however I still couldn't find the issue. As you can see Nos are sorted at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you traverse left or right, the call into traverse will print the left/right node. You don't have to print left and right separately.

```
if(n != null){
    if(n.getLeft() != null){
        result = traverse(n.getLeft()); 
        // System.out.println(result.getValue());                
    }

    result = n;
    System.out.println(result.getValue()); // This prints the left and right via recursion into traverse(...)

    if(n.getRight() != null){     
        result = traverse(n.getRight());
        // System.out.println(result.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse method should be:

```
void traverse(Node n) {
    if(n == null)
        return;

    traverse(n.getLeft());
    System.out.println(n.getValue());
    traverse(n.getRight());
}
```